# List index out of range error when getting column names from dict keys

Tags: python

I am trying to get some data from a site and keep encountering this error message

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-2f759e4acc91> in <module>
----> 1 fights_df = fights(fighters)

<ipython-input-118-be5e1cad2fca> in fights(list_of_boxers)
     31 
     32     #grab the column names from the dictionary keys of one event
---> 33     col_titles = r[0].keys()
     34 
     35     # create a list of values (remove the keys from the dictionary of each instance)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

From what I understand this means that the length of the list I am using as argument should have a length matching what I defined in my function.

Here is my code:

```
def fights(list_of_boxers):  
  dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
  for boxer in list_of_boxers: 
    headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "28",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host": "beta.compuboxdata.com",
    "Origin": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com.com",
    "Referer": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    } 
    dataload = {"page": "0",
            "result": "100",
            "fighter": boxer}
    t0 = time.time()
    r = requests.post('http://beta.compuboxdata.com/front/fighter/search', headers = headers, data = dataload )
    r = r.json()

    #grab the column names from the dictionary keys of one event
    col_titles = r[0].keys()

    # create a list of values (remove the keys from the dictionary of each instance)
    event_values = [list(event.values()) for event in r]

    #create a dataframe from the list of values
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns = col_titles) for i in event_values], ignore_index = True)

    dataframe = dataframe.append(df)


    response_delay = time.time() - t0
    time.sleep(0.5*response_delay)
    fights_df = fights(fighters)

  return dataframe
```

The full length of fighters is 6151
Here is a sample

```
['6690',
 '5631',
 '7281',
 '2643',
 '7099',
 '4719',
 '2555',
 '7244',
 '6807',
 '4550']
```

This is what i get if I comment out everything prior to

```
col_titles = r[0].keys()
```

Output:

```
[{'tot': '1',
  'event_id': '5648',
  'event_name': 'CAMABD03292014',
  'event_date': '2014-03-29',
  'title': '',
  'fighter1': 'CAMPFORT WILKY',
  'fighter2': 'ABDULLAEV KHURSHID',
  'fighter1id': '4549',
  'fighter2id': '4550',
  'fighter1ln': 'CAMPFORT',
  'fighter2ln': 'ABDULLAEV',
  'result': 'PAST'}]
```

Comment: Evidently "r" in that case is an empty list and has no element with index 0.

Comment: Your list should be empty when you try to access index 0. Print it before that to confirm.

Comment: @Clément Added the output I get when I comment out everything prior to accessing index 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a small fix to your code, which is to check for length of the dictionary/list before you try to access the element "if len(r) > 0:". That is why you get the error "IndexError: list index out of range". Below is the working code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time

def fights(list_of_boxers):
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    for boxer in list_of_boxers:
      headers = {
          "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Content-Length": "28",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          "Host": "beta.compuboxdata.com",
          "Origin": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com.com",
          "Referer": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter",
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      }
      dataload = {"page": "0",
                  "result": "100",
                  "fighter": boxer}
      t0 = time.time()
      r = requests.post('http://beta.compuboxdata.com/front/fighter/search', headers=headers, data=dataload)
      r = r.json()

      # grab the column names from the dictionary keys of one event
      if len(r) > 0:
          col_titles = r[0].keys()
          print(r)
          # create a list of values (remove the keys from the dictionary of each instance)
          event_values = [list(event.values()) for event in r]

          # create a dataframe from the list of values
          df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([i], columns=col_titles) for i in event_values], ignore_index=True)

          dataframe = dataframe.append(df)

          response_delay = time.time() - t0
          time.sleep(0.5 * response_delay)

    return dataframe

list_of_boxers = ['6690'
'5648',
'7281',
'2643',
'7099',
'4719',
'2555',
'7244',
'6807',
'4550']

fights(list_of_boxers)
```

and below is the screenshot of the code and the results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that some of your elements of your example do return an empty response, while others work. A quick workaround could be to catch the IndexError for these fighters and then continue. In this example the first entry returns an IndexError, while the second one is at least working until the variable `fighters` is reached.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import requests 
import time

def fights(list_of_boxers):  
  dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
  for boxer in list_of_boxers: 
    try:
      headers = {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Content-Length": "28",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
      "Host": "beta.compuboxdata.com",
      "Origin": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com.com",
      "Referer": "http://beta.compuboxdata.com/fighter",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      } 
      dataload = {"page": "0",
              "result": "100",
              "fighter": boxer}
      t0 = time.time()
      r = requests.post('http://beta.compuboxdata.com/front/fighter/search', headers = headers, data = dataload )

      r = r.json()

      #grab the column names from the dictionary keys of one event
      print(r)
      col_titles = r[0].keys()

      # rest of your code
      # ... 
      continue

    except IndexError as e:
      print(e)
      continue

    return dataframe

list_of_boxers = ['6690'
 '5648',
 '7281',
 '2643',
 '7099',
 '4719',
 '2555',
 '7244',
 '6807',
 '4550']

fights(list_of_boxers)
```

I still get errors with your code down the line, but this should at least help you with your IndexError. This gives me the following results:

```sh
[]
list index out of range
[{'tot': '1', 'event_id': '10856', 'event_name': 'AbaBAT11092019', 'event_date': '2019-11-09', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABABIY NIKITA', 'fighter2': 'BATISTA JONATHAN', 'fighter1id': '7281', 'fighter2id': '3900', 'fighter1ln': 'ABABIY', 'fighter2ln': 'BATISTA', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '8', 'event_id': '2243', 'event_name': 'ABAAND09292006', 'event_date': '2006-09-29', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter2': 'ANDINO YUKENCE', 'fighter1id': '2643', 'fighter2id': '2644', 'fighter1ln': 'ABALLE', 'fighter2ln': 'ANDINO', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '5869', 'event_name': 'ABAAND0V9292006', 'event_date': '2006-09-29', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter2': 'ANDINO YUKENCE', 'fighter1id': '2643', 'fighter2id': '2644', 'fighter1ln': 'ABALLE', 'fighter2ln': 'ANDINO', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6367', 'event_name': 'ABAABA03072015', 'event_date': '2015-03-07', 'title': 'test_dev', 'fighter1': 'ABADIA VICTOR', 'fighter2': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter1id': '1', 'fighter2id': '2643', 'fighter1ln': 'ABADIA', 'fighter2ln': 'ABALLE', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6368', 'event_name': 'ABAABA03082015', 'event_date': '2015-03-08', 
'title': 'test_dev1', 'fighter1': 'ABADIA VICTOR', 'fighter2': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter1id': '1', 'fighter2id': '2643', 'fighter1ln': 'ABADIA', 'fighter2ln': 'ABALLE', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6369', 'event_name': 'ABAABA03082015', 'event_date': '2015-03-08', 'title': 'test_dev2', 'fighter1': 'ABADIA VICTOR', 'fighter2': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter1id': '1', 'fighter2id': '2643', 'fighter1ln': 'ABADIA', 'fighter2ln': 'ABALLE', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6510', 'event_name': 'ABAABA04182015', 'event_date': '2015-04-18', 'title': 'test007', 'fighter1': 'ABADIA VICTOR', 'fighter2': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter1id': '1', 'fighter2id': '2643', 'fighter1ln': 'ABADIA', 'fighter2ln': 'ABALLE', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6538', 'event_name': 'ABAABE04262015', 'event_date': '2015-04-26', 'title': 'Test', 'fighter1': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter2': 'ABELL JOEY', 'fighter1id': 
'2643', 'fighter2id': '4758', 'fighter1ln': 'ABALLE', 'fighter2ln': 'ABELL', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '8', 'event_id': '6651', 'event_name': 'ABRABA05182015', 'event_date': '2015-05-18', 'title': 'Test', 'fighter1': 'ABREGU LUIS', 'fighter2': 'ABALLE CARLOS', 'fighter1id': '2912', 'fighter2id': '2643', 'fighter1ln': 'ABREGU', 'fighter2ln': 'ABALLE', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '2', 'event_id': '10495', 'event_name': 'CAIABA10282017', 'event_date': '2017-10-28', 'title': 'IBF', 'fighter1': 'CAI ZONGJU', 'fighter2': 'ABANIEL GRETCHEN', 'fighter1id': '7098', 'fighter2id': '7099', 'fighter1ln': 'CAI', 'fighter2ln': 'ABANIEL', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '2', 'event_id': '10510', 'event_name': 'ESTABA06132019', 'event_date': '2019-06-13', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ESTRADA SENIESA', 'fighter2': 'ABANIEL GRETCHEN', 'fighter1id': '5685', 'fighter2id': '7099', 'fighter1ln': 'ESTRADA', 'fighter2ln': 'ABANIEL', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '3', 'event_id': '5976', 'event_name': 'ABBBRE10182014', 'event_date': '2014-10-18', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABBRUZZESE ANTHONY', 'fighter2': 'PRESCOTT ANTHONY', 'fighter1id': '4719', 'fighter2id': '4720', 'fighter1ln': 'ABBRUZZESE', 'fighter2ln': 'PRESCOTT', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '6546', 'event_name': 'ABBABR04272015', 'event_date': '2015-04-27', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABBRUZZESE ANTHONY', 'fighter2': 'ABRIL RICHARD', 'fighter1id': '4719', 'fighter2id': '3452', 'fighter1ln': 'ABBRUZZESE', 'fighter2ln': 'ABRIL', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '7153', 'event_name': 'ABBGAL11032015', 'event_date': '2015-11-03', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABBRUZZESE ANTHONY', 'fighter2': 'GALVAN RUBEN', 'fighter1id': '4719', 'fighter2id': '2437', 'fighter1ln': 'ABBRUZZESE', 'fighter2ln': 'GALVAN', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '2', 'event_id': '2381', 'event_name': 'DAMABD04192002', 'event_date': '2002-04-19', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'DAMGAARD THOMAS', 'fighter2': 'ABDELHAKUM MEHIDI', 'fighter1id': '2554', 'fighter2id': '2555', 'fighter1ln': 'DAMGAARD', 'fighter2ln': 'ABDELHAKUM', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '2', 'event_id': '6474', 'event_name': 'ABDABD04022015', 'event_date': '2015-04-02', 'title': 'pause test', 'fighter1': 'ABDELHAKUM MEHIDI', 'fighter2': 'ABDULAEV MOHAMAD', 'fighter1id': '2555', 'fighter2id': '3', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDELHAKUM', 'fighter2ln': 'ABDULAEV', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10792', 'event_name': 'ABDTOT03172018', 'event_date': '2018-03-17', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABDUKAKHOROV KUDRATILLO', 'fighter2': 'TOTH LASZLO', 'fighter1id': '7244', 'fighter2id': '7245', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDUKAKHOROV', 'fighter2ln': 'TOTH', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10793', 'event_name': 'ABDOBA03302019', 'event_date': '2019-03-30', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABDUKAKHOROV KUDRATILLO', 'fighter2': 'OBARA KEITA', 'fighter1id': '7244', 'fighter2id': '5330', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDUKAKHOROV', 'fighter2ln': 'OBARA', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10803', 'event_name': 'ABDCOL10182019', 'event_date': '2019-10-18', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABDUKAKHOROV KUDRATILLO', 'fighter2': 'COLLAZO LUIS', 'fighter1id': '7244', 'fighter2id': '2599', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDUKAKHOROV', 'fighter2ln': 'COLLAZO', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10006', 'event_name': 'ABDLUN09072018', 'event_date': '2018-09-07', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABDULLAEV ZAUR', 'fighter2': 'LUNDY HANK', 'fighter1id': '6807', 'fighter2id': '3056', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDULLAEV', 'fighter2ln': 'LUNDY', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10678', 'event_name': 'ABDMAR02222019', 'event_date': '2019-02-22', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'ABDULLAEV ZAUR', 'fighter2': 'MARTINEZ HUMBERTO', 'fighter1id': '6807', 'fighter2id': '7184', 'fighter1ln': 'ABDULLAEV', 'fighter2ln': 'MARTINEZ', 'result': 'PAST'}, {'tot': '3', 'event_id': '10734', 'event_name': 'HANABD09132019', 'event_date': '2019-09-13', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'HANEY DEVIN', 'fighter2': 'ABDULLAEV ZAUR', 'fighter1id': '6339', 'fighter2id': '6807', 'fighter1ln': 'HANEY', 'fighter2ln': 'ABDULLAEV', 'result': 'PAST'}]
[{'tot': '1', 'event_id': '5648', 'event_name': 'CAMABD03292014', 'event_date': '2014-03-29', 'title': '', 'fighter1': 'CAMPFORT WILKY', 'fighter2': 'ABDULLAEV KHURSHID', 'fighter1id': '4549', 'fighter2id': '4550', 'fighter1ln': 'CAMPFORT', 'fighter2ln': 'ABDULLAEV', 'result': 'PAST'}]
```

Comment: maybe i'm doing something wrong, but ran this code and getting the same name repeated multiple times - seemingly endlessly